# User authentication via HTTP endpoints

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I wonder how a user is signed in using the HTTP endpoints. The doc [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/auth-types) suggests:

```
User Authentication:

curl -X POST "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/users/get_current_account" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer <OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN>"
```

But `OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` is supposed to be generated by the authentication server. How does the client obtain `OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` via HTTP endpoints?

Comment: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/ this is how you can generate your access token. The application server to which you make the request will check with `OAUTH` server to check what user you're and if you're authenticated(Internally).

Comment: @harshil9968 But if the user is to sign into Dropbox via my client, how is the access token meant to be generated? The generation method you pointed to is for the developer's own token. Also, it actually says "To obtain access tokens for other users, use the standard OAuth flow". But I can't find end points for this.

Comment: If it has to sign in with your app, then you need to make an app in dropbox account.

Comment: @harshil9968 What do you mean an app in dropbox account?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps

Comment: @harshil9968 Yes I've done that. But how do I access obtain the access token for the user in order to authenticate calls to HTTP endpoints? Like in the original question, how do I obtain `OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN` for the user in order to call `get_current_account` to grab the user's account data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dropbox OAuth 2 access token for the end-user should be retrieved by sending the user through the Dropbox OAuth 2 app authorization flow. The endpoints for this flow are documented here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization

This blog post outlines the process:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/07/using-oauth-2-0-with-the-core-api/

(It was written for API v1, but the OAuth 2 flow works the same way for API v2.)

The OAuth guide may also serve as a useful reference:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide